# Not able to switch one fragment to another in android

Tags: java, android

Error shows can not cast Highlight to Fragment and can not cast Overview to Fragment and error comes only in selectFrag() method. Please any one help me to fix this problem. I want to switch one fragment to other when i click on textview item.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }        

     public void selectFrag(View view){      
        Fragment fr;
        if (view == findViewById(R.id.txt_highlite)) {          
        fr = (Fragment) new Highlight();
        }
        else{
            fr = (Fragment) new Overview();
        }       
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.place_holder, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
    }
```

//Highlight class

```
public class Highlight extends Fragment {   
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.highlight, container, false);
    }
}
```

//Overview class

```
public class Overview extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview, container, false);
    }
}
```

//activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >    
      <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin_projectoverview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_Projectoverview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Project Overview"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/project_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"          
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_overview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:text="Overview" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_highlite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:text="Highlight" />            
        </LinearLayout>          
    </RelativeLayout>   

     <fragment 
          android:name="com.example.fragment_move.Overview"
          android:id="@+id/place_holder"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please paste `import`s of your classes.

Answer (score 0):

Check your import statements. Based on your `getFragmentManager()`, your every class that extends `Fragment` should have only this fragment import:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

Answer (score 0):

Highlight and Overview already inherits from Fragment,so why are u casting them to fragments again? 
I will suggest you do it this way.

```
 public void selectFrag(View view){      
    Fragment fr;
    if (view.getId() == R.id.txt_highlite) {          
    fr = new Highlight();
    }
    else{
        fr =  new Overview();
    }       
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.place_holder, fr);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
   }
```

and ensure your Fragment importations are consistently  either from the Support library or otherwise